535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed using PHPMailer on Hostinger, user and password are correct
I've been trying to create a contact form for my site using PHPMailer because it seemed like the easiest option for what I'm trying to do. I host my website on Hostinger, and I'm using their "Titan Mail" to send my emails. I'm new to PHP and dealing with backend stuff as a whole, so I'm not really sure where to go next.
Hostinger's help article said I should use this code to send a test email to make sure it works:
<?php
   require 'vendor/autoload.php';
   use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
   $mail = new PHPMailer;
   $mail->isSMTP();
   $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
   $mail->Host = 'smtp.titan.email';
   $mail->Port = 587;
   $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
   $mail->Username = 'mymail@myawesomedomain.tld';
   $mail->Password = 'My$tr0ngPa55w0rd!';
   $mail->setFrom('mymail@myawesomedomain.tld', 'Your Name');
   $mail->addReplyTo('mymail@myawesomedomain.tld', 'Your Name');
   $mail->addAddress('recipient@domain.tld', 'Receiver Name');
   $mail->Subject = 'Checking if PHPMailer works';
   $mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('message.html'), __DIR__);
   $mail->Body = 'This is just a plain text message body';
   //$mail->addAttachment('attachment.txt');
   if (!$mail->send()) {
       echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   } else {
       echo 'The email message was sent.';
   }
?>

This didn't work, I also tried it with the host as "smtp.hostinger.com" with no luck. I entered my username and password etc., but when I run the script it spits out this error:
2024-07-08 14:28:21 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp-out.flockmail.com ESMTP Postfix
2024-07-08 14:28:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO {MY-DOMAIN-NAME}
2024-07-08 14:28:21 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp-out.flockmail.com250-PIPELINING250-SIZE 52428800250-VRFY250-ETRN250-STARTTLS250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-8BITMIME250-DSN250 CHUNKING
2024-07-08 14:28:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2024-07-08 14:28:21 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
2024-07-08 14:28:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO {MY-DOMAIN-NAME}
2024-07-08 14:28:21 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp-out.flockmail.com250-PIPELINING250-SIZE 52428800250-VRFY250-ETRN250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-8BITMIME250-DSN250 CHUNKING
2024-07-08 14:28:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2024-07-08 14:28:21 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
2024-07-08 14:28:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
2024-07-08 14:28:21 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
2024-07-08 14:28:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
2024-07-08 14:28:23 SERVER -> CLIENT: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
2024-07-08 14:28:23 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2024-07-08 14:28:23 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2024-07-08 14:28:23 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Bye
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

I've googled the error code and looked at pretty much every result, people are saying that the credentials are incorrect, which isn't true(to the best of my knowledge). I tried to change the port to 465, different host name, no luck. Any ideas on what's going wrong?

It's suspicious that you're asking it to connect to smtp.hostinger.com, but the server replies saying it's smtp-out.flockmail.com, i.e. not the same. If this really is mismatched, it should be caught by TLS, but a common cause for auth failing is that you're not connecting to the server you thought you were.

hmmm, that's definitely weird now that you point that out, I should clarify(and I'll update the post with this) that the error message that I pasted came from when I had the host as "smtp.titan.email". is that any different in your eyes? Regardless I'll do some more digging with that in mind.

The SMTP settings for Titan Mail (as provided by Hostinger) should be as follows:
SMTP Server: smtp.titan.email
SMTP Port: 587 for TLS or 465 for SSL

I tried using these settings, 587 results in the error in my post, 465 results in the page loading forever and timing out. thoughts?

Tried everything, and this actually worked, though I got it in the spam, which I'm not sure if it was supposed to happen...
